# Stomach Cancer dying as martyr?

Tags: sharia, fiqh, martyr

If someone dies having stomach cancer will they become a martyr in Jannah and have their sins forgiven? I know its for diarrhea, drowning, wall falling and ofc Jihad but what about Stomach Cancer?

Comment: I am afraid if you declare everyone dying from any disease than that will be too much. Also this status of martyr is not FULL FLEDGE, i heard their are 70 levels of martyr, and this type of martyr who is not martyred in a fight for islam gets only 1 of those.

Comment: One can't confirm it nor deny it totally

Answer (score 1):

In the name of Allah.

Salaam,

In the hadith of the prophet (peace be on him) he said:

حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو عَاصِمٍ، عَنْ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ سُمَىٍّ، عَنْ أَبِي صَالِحٍ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ الْمَبْطُونُ شَهِيدٌ، وَالْمَطْعُونُ شَهِيدٌ ‏"‏‏.‏

The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "He (a Muslim) who dies of an abdominal disease is a martyr, and he who dies of plague is a martyr."

http://sunnah.com/bukhari/76/48

Sahih al-Bukhari 5733

Allah knows best.

Comment: Evidences are good, but they are not self-explanatory. Please consider reading [answer] and *editing* your answer and elaborating how your evidence should be understood!